# Is the common zero locus of a collection of polynomials always equal to the common zero locus of a finite subcollection of those polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I've been studying the basics of algebraic geometry using Fulton's book *Algebraic Curves*. One of the first theorems proven is that for a field $k$, if $S\subseteq k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, then $V(S)=V(T)$ for some *finite* subset $T\subseteq k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$; this is a corollary of Hilbert's basis theorem.

My question is: is it always possible to write $V(S)$ as $V(T)$, where $T$ is a *finite subset of $S$*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ is noetherian, $(S)$ is finitely generated, say by $f_1,\cdots,f_m$. Express each $f_i$ in terms of the elements of $S$, and note that each expression only uses finitely many elements of $S$, so the collection of all elements of $S$ necessary to obtain the $f_i$ suffices as a finite generating set of $(S)$. Therefore $V(S)=V((S))$ is the common zero locus of these finitely many elements of $S$.